# how to over ride request object in ServletRequestWrapper?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to over ride the default `getParameter()` method of `ServletRequestWrapper` with `getParameter()` method of `SecurityRequestWrapper`.

For example, if I am using a simple jsp form to take the name of a person,

```
String name = request.getParameter("firstName");
```

I want the above `getParameter()` method to be from the `SecurityRequestWrapper` class. I am not able to understand how the request object is over riden since the `getParameter` method is mostly called on it by default in any jsp form.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the `SecurityRequestWrapper` you're talking about already implements [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)? If so, then just create a `Filter` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsp` (or whatever you'd like to invoke this `Filter` for) and does basically the following in the `doFilter()` method.

```
chain.doFilter(new SecurityRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request, response));
```

Comment: This is great,I was stupid to not think of this filter approach.

Comment: @Shamik: You can find several use examples in the related answers I ever posted here: [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=httpservletrequestwrapper+user%3A157882) and [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=httpservletresponsewrapper+user%3A157882).

Answer (score -2):

I might be wrong, but I do not think this is possible. Because request and response objects are created by the container and passed onto the servlet's process method. The very reason these objects are created by the container, because they want to flush the output and would like to control that. I will be interested to know however if it is possible to pass our own request / response objects.

Comment: You're wrong. Have a look at `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and `HttpServletReponseWrapper`.